# I can't send a URL in a form

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, url, http-status-code-301

```
<form action="http://xxx.xxx/Komore/index.php/komore/dodaj_komoro" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <input id="d1" name="datum" value="<?php echo set_value('datum'); ?>" class="TextBox4" />
    <input name="dimenzije" value="<?php echo set_value('dimenzije'); ?>" class="TextBox4"  />
    <input name="meritve1" value="<?php echo set_value('meritve1'); ?>" class="TextBox5" />
    <input name="meritve2" value="<?php echo set_value('meritve2'); ?>" class="TextBox6" id="m1"/>
    <input name="meritve3" value="<?php echo set_value('meritve3'); ?>" class="TextBox7" id="m2"/>
    <input name="meritve4" value="<?php echo set_value('meritve4'); ?>" class="TextBox8" id="m3" />
    <input name="doba" class="TextBox9" value="<?php echo set_value('doba');?>" />
    <textarea name="opombe" value="<?php echo set_value('opombe'); ?>" class="textarea1" ></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Dodaj komoro"  Text="Dodaj komoro"/>
</form>
```

I have a form, through which I send data, in one the fields the user must a enter an URL address. When the URL is actually in the form I get a 301 response which redirects me to xxx.xxx/Komore/komore/dodaj_komoro which doesn't exist. Strange enough this doesn't happen on localhost and it also doesn't happen when the value is not a URL address. Any ideas?

The code in php controller dodaj_komoro(the request doesn't even reach this code if there is an URL inside):

```
public function dodaj_komoro(){
        $this->load->model('Komore_model');
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('st_komore', 'Številka komore', "required|xss_clean");
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('premer', 'Notranji premer', "required|xss_clean");
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('proizvajalec', 'Proizvajalec', "required|xss_clean");
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('datum', 'Datum prevzema', "required|xss_clean");
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('dimenzije', 'Dimenzije komore', "required|xss_clean");
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('meritve1','Meritve',"required|xss_clean");
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('meritve2','Meritve',"required|xss_clean");
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('meritve3','Meritve',"required|xss_clean");
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('meritve4','Meritve',"required|xss_clean");
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('opombe','Opombe',"");
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('doba','Življenska doba',"required|xss_clean");

        $this->form_validation->set_message('required', '<div class="error">Polje %s je obvezno.</div>');
        $this->form_validation->set_message('xss_clean', '<div class="error">Polje %s vsebuje neveljavne znake.</div>');
        if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            $komore=$this->Komore_model->get_komore_stats_by_type($_POST["id_tip_komore"]);
            $tip_komore=$this->Komore_model->get_komora_oznaka($_POST["id_tip_komore"]);
            $this->load->view("komore",array("komore"=>$komore,"tip_komore"=>$tip_komore,"id_tip_komore"=>$_POST["id_tip_komore"]));
        }else{
            $meritve=$_POST["meritve1"].";".$_POST["meritve2"].";".$_POST["meritve3"].";".$_POST["meritve4"];
            $this->Komore_model->add_komora($_POST["id_tip_komore"],$_POST["premer"],$_POST["proizvajalec"],$_POST["datum"],$_POST["dimenzije"],$meritve,$_POST["opombe"],$_POST["st_komore"],$_POST["doba"]);
            redirect("komore/tip_komore/".$_POST["id_tip_komore"]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Which field is for URL address?

Comment: name="dimenzije" is the field

Comment: Your form closing tag is not in its place !!

Comment: JC I made a mistake copying, it is not the issue otherwise.

Comment: Does it redirects to the same URL which user has entered in the text field? Please explain when redirect happens.

Comment: first of all, it is not about form and php code at all. If I got you right, when you type in your browser: `http://localhost/Komore/index.php/komore/dodaj_komoro` you see something like a page generated by CI, but when you type `http://example.com/Komore/index.php/komore/dodaj_komoro` you've got 301 error. I would say it again *even if you type it just in browser*. That mean that you have different settings for localhost and for real domain. So what is your index path to CI page in `localhost` and what is for `example.com`

Comment: Everything seems working as expected, I don't see where is the problem

Comment: Kim, you basically got it right, but if I just type the address in the browser I get a CI page, the problem only occurs when I add an URL in the form on the server.

Comment: wait a sec??? you can reach `http://example.com/Komore/index.php/komore/dodaj_komoro` in browser? are you sure?

Comment: IDK if its related to your problem, but you are filling wrong the textarea value. It should be `<textarea name="opombe" class="textarea1"><?php echo set_value('opombe'); ?></textarea>`. There's no "value" attribute for textarea.

Comment: Yes I can reach http://example.com/Komore/index.php/komore/dodaj_komoro, I get some errors because the parametres aren't set, but yes I can reach it. I can't reach http://example.com/Komore/komore/dodaj_komoro

Comment: so, you have to check if you can reach `http://localhost/Komore/komore/dodaj_komoro` first. and after check your `.htaccess` files in CI root folder for `localhost` and for `example.com`

Comment: I can't access http://localhost/Komore/komore/dodaj_komoro. the .htaccess files are the same.

Comment: could you add `.htaccess` file content to your question body please? By the way, compare your `application/config/routes.php` for `localhost` and `exmple.com` either.

Comment: I have an empty .htaccess file, I don't have any rewrite rules or anything.

Comment: Dou you have public link to your `example.com/codeigniter/` ?

Comment: What is that? I haven't done anything like that.

Comment: what is your real value of `example.com` ??

Comment: I am sorry I don't know what you are talking about.

Comment: you don't know what is your question about? You've asked about strange behavior of your application on SOMEHOST (ex : xxx.xxx, example.com) and you've said that your code works fine on you localhost. So I ask you if I can see/visit your (xxx.xxx, example.com) some host. So what is your domain?? do you have  a link I can visit and see your form?

Comment: oh, I'm sorry http://nklocan.si/ is the address.

Comment: http://nklocan.si/Komore to the codeigniter

Comment: what login pass can I use?

Comment: ok, I logged in as tes/test, where is your page with the form?

Answer (score 0):

Check your htaccess.txt file.

My guess that you have rewrite mode rule that causing the problem.